# Free tier, gcloud source repos clone : This API method requires billing to be enabled

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I created a Google App Engine years ago. It is using standard Python 2.7, and I created it using the free tier. There is a simple Python project (3~4 files), and today I wanted to add a file to it for testing. I have not used it for so long that I forgot how I did it before. Anyway, I tried `gcloud source repos clone` or `gcloud source repos list`, but all those commands gave same error.

> Error: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) PERMISSION_DENIED: This API method requires billing to be enabled. Pleae enable billing on project #(number) by visiting https://console...

I rechecked their pricing page, and it seams they are still providing free tier. Then, why does it require billing just to download the source files of my own project or even the `python-gae-quickstart`. Did I do somethin wrong, or does it now require billing for even free tiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free tier is based upon usage of certain resources, they need you to have a valid and enabled Billing account on the project in case you exceed the usage of the Free Tier.

For example, according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free), App Engine has 1 GB of egress per day; however, in case you exceed said daily usage, you will be billed for the difference.

Keep in mind that they do not know what happens on the project, so even if you just want to download something or are not going to use any API, they will still ask you for a billing account.

If you have more doubts, contact their billing support over [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing?hl=pl), and they should be able to provide further help.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am sure that it had not required enabling billing a few years ago, otherwise I would not have been able to upload the code files that are currently on the project. If what you are saying is true, then it seems that Google have changed their policy to require billing information at any case. I think back when I started it, Google would have just temporarily suspended the project if it exceeded the free quota, instead of billing money.